# jQuery UI Dialog and pjax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, pjax

I'm using pjax in a web app that has some jQuery UI dialogs.

The problem I'm running into is that the div element used to create the dialog is moved out of its container in the dom when the dialog is created.

When pjax loads a new page, the dialog div is not destroyed because it no longer lives inside the container that pjax loads content into. When pjax navigates back to the page with the dialog, it loads a second copy of the div element and everything gets buggy because of the duplicated elements living in the dom.

Has anyone found an elegant solution to this problem? Is there a way to clean up all the dom changes made by the jQuery UI dialog call?

I should also mention that the issue isn't specific to pjax. The same thing happens if I simply use $("#mycontainer").load("page-with-dialog.html");

Answer (score 0):

set the div style to display:none and reuse the same one, don't destroy it.

```
<div id="dialog" class="ui-helper-hidden">
</div>
```

Comment: I always keep dialog divs in the body. They should be isolated.

Comment: Say I have main.html with a <div id='container'></div> and dlgpage.html with <div id="dlg">My Dialog</div> main.html calls $("#container").load("dlgpage.html"). When it loads, some jquery executes to turn 'dlg' into a jquery UI dialog. The dialog works, but in the dom it has now moved outside of the 'container' div. If main.html calls $("#container").load("newpage.html") everything that was in the 'container' div is removed and replaced with the new content, but the dialog element remains in the dom. Calling $("#container").load("dlgpage.html") again will then duplicate mydialog in the DOM.

Comment: Ended up adding a line in pjax.js to clean up dialogs before loading new content. Works for now I guess.